# Should self-revival be allowed?

Tags: discussion, badges, revival-badge

Over on Stack Overflow I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211742/compile-lua-without-automatic-conversion-between-strings-and-numbers/23223994#23223994) that sat unanswered for over a month. I then noticed that one of the comments was actually an authoritative answer, and so added it as an answer and accepted it.

A couple upvotes later and I got the Revival badge. Not that I don't appreciate more bling, but this seems wrong to me. However, unlikely, I worry that this will encourage users to 'bump' their old unanswered questions with an answer and maybe get a bronze badge out of it.

Probably a minor deal, but: **should the asker of a question be allowed to get a Revival for their own answer**? I think perhaps not.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not sure how much of a problem this really is.

Comment: I'll echo @Linuxios here, what harm is being caused? What if you worked on a problem for 30 days and finally found an answer that nobody else had?

Comment: Absolutely they should. Upvotes mean the answer was useful. If the badge encourages users to do that, that's excellent!

Comment: If it feels wrong to you, leave a comment to the person who "answered" the question in comment, suggesting they post an answer.

Answer (score 11):

Bumping their unanswered question with a quality answer is not a bad thing.  It is a good thing.  Being rewarded for doing a good thing is a good thing.

If you were bumping the question with low quality contributions, i.e. non answers posted as answers, pointless edits, etc. to give it more attention *without adding value* then that would be a problem.  There are means of addressing those problems when they come up, but none of them are the case here.

Comment: And since revival requires upvotes, bumping with low quality posts shouldn't earn anyone the badge.